# How to take guess a word by its letter in js

Tags: javascript, html

as the title says I'm making a little game, but it doesn't guess the word, I don't know why. I've added a word so people would have to guess it, using letters and if the letter is equal to any letter on the word it would replace the _.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Story</title>
    <style>
        /*body {
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: 13.5pt;
            margin-left: 5px;
            color: black;
        }*/

        #aa{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        /*.in2{
            width: 300px;
            height: 630px;
            border: 0px solid white;
            background-color: white;
            color: white;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 25pt;
        }*/
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var word = "" //word variable
        var wLength = 0 //word length variable
        var dummy = "" //letter guessed
        var dm = new Array(26)


        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input.in2").hide()
        })

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input.bi2").hide()
        })

        function doGetWord(){
            var word = F.gword.value;
            var wLength = word.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < wLength; i++){
                document.getElementById("dword").innerHTML += "_ "
            }
            $("input.wordi").hide()
            $("input.bi").hide()
            $("input.in2").show()
            $("input.bi2").show()
        }

        function doGuess(){
            dummy = F.t.value
            if(dummy.length > 1){
                dummy = ""
                F.t.value = ""
            }
            else{
                F.t.value = ""
                alp = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
                dd = dummy.toString()
                window["cl" + dd]
                if(window["cl" + dd] == false){
                    alert("Letter already used, please try again with another letter")
                    dummy = ""
                    F.t.value = ""
                }
                else{
                    window["cl" + dd] = false
                    F.t.value = ""
                    doGuessWord();
                }
            }
        }

        function doGuessWord(){
            ws = new Array(wLength);
            for(i = 0; i <= wLength; i++){
                ws[i] = word.charAt(i)
                if(dummy == ws[i]){
                    document.getElementById("dword").value.charAt(i) = dummy
                }
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="F">
        <input type="text" name="gword" class="wordi">
        <input type="text" name="t" class="in2">
        <input type="button" name="b" value="do" onclick="doGetWord()" class="bi">
        <input type="button" name="b2" value="do" onclick="doGuess()" class="bi2">
        <div id="dword"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me figure out what the error is? I just can't find it but I think it has something to do with the `document.getElementById("dword").value.charAt(i) = dummy`.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What does your `console.log` say?

Comment: No errors at all on it.

Comment: Where do you specify which word has to be guessed? Also, I don't know which javascript tutorial are you following, but you should not use the `window` object like you do in your code. There are simple arrays in javascript.

Comment: Also you're missing about half your semicolons .. This is bad practice and  can also confuse JavaScript ..

Comment: dword is div, right? Div does not have value property, use textContent....

Comment: the word that has to be guessed is the variable word. And I didn't really knew how to use the window thing. Could u help me out with this one?

Comment: but aren't semicolons useless in js? xD

Comment: yes sir, dword is the div, and thanks for the advise.

Comment: semi-colons separate statements you're making to your Browser. If you don't supply them the Browser guesses. You should always supply them.

Comment: Oh okay, I did not know that, thanks a lot. Do you know what's wrong with the rest of my code?

Comment: @zfrisch is right. There are so many things wrong about your code I really don't know where to start. I will simply recommend  this book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/   Just be aware that wherever you are learning JS from, is full of bad practices, so take your time and get a decent knowledge of the basics before you try to write complex programs. PS: just saying that because you seem to have fun with but you can save yourself lots of headaches if you start right.  Also: read Stack Overflow.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `var` before variables here

```
function doGetWord(){
            var word = F.gword.value;
            var wLength = word.length;
```

As the idea is to save this values in scope of parent function.
And you might replace the letters like this

```
const letters = document.getElementById("dword").textContent.split('');
letters[i] = dummy;
document.getElementById("dword").textContent = letters.join('');
```

You are using bad variable names and a lot of global variables, it might be a good practice to work of this. I recommend reading a book on general programming, something like [https://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) and something more specific to javascript (to get the concept of scopes) https://www.manning.com/books/secrets-of-the-javascript-ninja

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <title>Story</title>
        <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            /*body {
                font-family: Calibri;
                font-size: 13.5pt;
                margin-left: 5px;
                color: black;
            }*/

            #aa{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            /*.in2{
                width: 300px;
                height: 630px;
                border: 0px solid white;
                background-color: white;
                color: white;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 25pt;
            }*/
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var word = "" //word variable
            var wLength = 0 //word length variable
            var dummy = "" //letter guessed
            var dm = new Array(26)


            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("input.in2").hide()
            })

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("input.bi2").hide()
            })

            function doGetWord(){
                word = F.gword.value;
                wLength = word.length;
                for(var i = 0; i < wLength; i++){
                    document.getElementById("dword").innerHTML += "_ "
                }
                $("input.wordi").hide()
                $("input.bi").hide()
                $("input.in2").show()
                $("input.bi2").show()
            }

            function doGuess(){
                dummy = F.t.value
                if(dummy.length > 1){
                    dummy = ""
                    F.t.value = ""
                }
                else{
                    F.t.value = ""
                    alp = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
                    dd = dummy.toString()
                    window["cl" + dd]
                    if(window["cl" + dd] == false){
                        alert("Letter already used, please try again with another letter")
                        dummy = ""
                        F.t.value = ""
                    }
                    else{
                        window["cl" + dd] = false
                        F.t.value = ""
                        doGuessWord();
                    }
                }
            }

            function doGuessWord(){
                const letters = document.getElementById("dword").textContent.split(' ');
                for(i = 0; i < wLength; i++){
                    if(dummy === word.charAt(i)) {
                        letters[i] = dummy;
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("dword").textContent = letters.join(' ');
            }
        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <form name="F">
          <input type="text" name="gword" class="wordi" />
          <input type="text" name="t" class="in2" />
          <input type="button" name="b" value="do" onclick="doGetWord()" class="bi" />
          <input type="button" name="b2" value="do" onclick="doGuess()" class="bi2" />
          <div id="dword"></div>
        </form>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: your does kinda work but it still has the _. Could u please remove them and also explain what did you change? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how do I remove the "_" from the word after it has been guessed?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The changes were made in `doGuessWord`

Comment: Omg, thank you so much for everything, ur post was very useful :=).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints on your code (among other things):

1. It's always better to use semi-colons (as noted by zfrisch).
2. You don't need more than one `$(document).ready(function() { .. })`.
3. `String`s are immutable, so you cannot change them directly. You have to turn them into `char` arrays first (as in Bsalex answer).
4. Don't declare local variables with the same names as global variables, because the local ones will *hide* the globals.
5. To read the text content of a `div` element, use its `textContent` property instead of `value`. (see Bsalex answer)
6. Don't declare a local variable without `var`/`let`/`const` keywords (like this `ws = new Array(wLength)`), or it'll become a global variable.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your time, and for what you just said. By the way could you explain number 2? pls, thanks xD

Comment: @ThecheesiestChannel It means, you can simply place both statements of (`$("input.in2").hide()` and `$("input.bi2").hide()`) in a single `$(document).ready(function(){..})`, instead of two.

Comment: oh ok tyty ahah xD